# How does Tesseract use OpenCL?

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpu, tesseract

I am working on a project that requires me to speed up the process of text recognition using Tesseract. I came across an [article](http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-meets-the-opencl-first-test) which said Tesseract is working in conjunction with OpenCL to offload some of the compute intensive tasks onto the CPU or GPUs available.
Is there a qualitative explanation on how 'Tesseract is making use of OpenCL to offload the compute intensive tasks on to parallel CPU cores or GPUs'?

The link to the Tesseract source is here https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/#git%2Fopencl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract is an OCR, so it is detecting patterns/letters in an image. This is roughly speaking image processing, where each pixel can be computed in parallel, therefore a very good candidate for GPU (OpenCL/CUDA/etc..).

How in details it is being used will be complicated to understand, but basically it is processing the following things in OpenCL (as printed by the profiling code):

```
 composeRGBPixel: 0.073872 (w=1.2)
 HistogramRect: 0.121674 (w=2.4)
 ThresholdRectToPix: 0.050257 (w=4.5)
 getLineMasksMorph: 0.350409 (w=5.0)
```

So basically, is doing some pixel conversion in GPU (very efficient), then an histogram and finally thresholding the image.

The profiling code is just measuring the time taken by each OpenCL device, and selecting the best one. Other approaches are possible.

After it select a best device, it is the task of the device to do the compute load. In the case of GPU it will use all the shading cores (compute cores). In case of CPU it will simply run a thread pool. But no GPU-CPU work balance will be done by OpenCL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My objective is to speed up the text recognition process using Tesseract. Instead of sending an entire image to Tesseract, I have split the image into multiple parts and use OpenCL to process this in multiple cores of my CPU or the GPU. Will I be able to get any speedup? Or has Tesseract already saturated the GPU/ CPU cores by using OpenCL?

Comment: OpenCL saturates the cores of the device it uses. At most, you can split the processing in multiple devices (CPU and GPU). But given that CPUs are much slower for OpenCL tasks (lets say 10 to 1), I think the overhead of using multiple devices (splitting, merging, etc...) will not make it worth.

Comment: So do you have any suggestions to improve the speed of Tesseract text extraction? Right now, it takes about 10 - 15 seconds per image, depending on the size of the image.

Comment: Let me know if you get it working.  I've been trying to use Tesseract 3.03-rc1 with OpenCL but it segfaults.  The sample programs in the AMD SDK run fine though -- at least the ones using single precision.  My GPU apparently doesn't support double.